# how to use json in asp.net 2003

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-1.1

I am using the JSON object with jquery in asp.net application. The code is working with VS2008 but when i moved sam code in VS2003 then it is showing the JSON is undefined. Code is following

```
var mes = $('#filePath').val();
alert("File Path: " + mes);
var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ sFilePath: mes });
```

In third line it is giving the error :
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined

Can any one help on this. Do i need to add any reference.

Thanks in Advance
Eshwer N

Answer (score 3):

This does not smell like an ASP.NET issue.  Rather try including the json2.js as part of your script tags -

http://www.json.org/

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

http://www.json.org/js.html

```
<script src="http://wherever.com/json2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: hi Kris, thanks for reply. i used this step but still same error... any other suggetions!!